# jQuery-UI dialog with jQuery 1.9.0

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I use jQuery dialog on my pages. After I upgraded the jQuery version from 1.8 to 1.9 my dialog div is visible on the page before I click the button to open up the dialog page.

When I used jq 1.8 the code below worked and the `#form` was invisible until I clicked the `button`. Now I upgraded to jq1.9 the `#form` is visible on the page. Any idea why and how can I resolve this?

```
$(document).on('click', '.button', function(){
    $("#form").dialog("open"); 
});

<div id="form" title="Create new">
   <form>
     <label for="name">Name</label>
     <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
   </form>
</div>
```

Comment: did you update the jquery ui CSS and the HTML structure for the new version of jQuery UI?

Comment: Where is `button` class in your html?

Comment: @KevinB No, I didn't.

Comment: I don't understand why #form would be invisible. There doesn't seem to be a style on it making it invisible. Are you saying the div is visible in its normal location on the page when it shouldn't be, or are you saying that the dialog is opening too soon?

Comment: Did you uprade jQuery from 1.8 to 1.9; and jQuery UI?

Answer (score 0):

Update your JS as follows:

```
$("#form").dialog({ autoOpen: false });

$(document).on('click', '.button', function(){
    $("#form").dialog("open"); 
});
```

`autoOpen` is `true` by default (it was in 1.8 too, to be fair)